# Restriction-extension identities using six functors formalism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, adjoint-functors, derived-functors, derived-categories

Recently fellow user [Thorgott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/422019/thorgott) pointed out to me that flat restrictions of flat modules remain flat. That is, let $f : A \to B$ be a flat morphism of rings and $M$ be a flat $B$-module. Then considering $M$ as an $A$-module by basechanging along $f$, it is still flat.

The proof goes as follows: Let $Q \to N$ be an injection of $A$-module. Tensoring with $B$ over $A$, we obtain an injection $Q \otimes_A B \to N \otimes_A B$, by flatness of $B$ as an $A$-module using the module structure coming from $f$. We can further tensor with $M$ as a $B$-module to obtain an injection $(Q \otimes_A B) \otimes_B M \to (N \otimes_A B) \otimes_B M$ by using flatness of $M$ as a $B$-module this time. At this point Thorgott observes that $(N \otimes_A B) \otimes_B M$ is naturally isomorphic as $A$-modules to $N \otimes_A M$, with the isomorphism given by $(N \otimes_A B) \otimes_B M \to N \otimes_A M$, $(x \otimes_A b) \otimes_B m \mapsto x \otimes_A bm$. This is straightforward to check.

Here is a curious way to state the identity. Let $f_* : \mathsf{Mod}_B \to \mathsf{Mod}_A$ be restriction of scalars functor and $f^* : \mathsf{Mod}_A \to \mathsf{Mod}_B$ be extension of scalars functor. Then for an $A$-module $N$ and a $B$-module $M$, there is a natural isomorphism: $$N \otimes_A f_* M \cong_{\mathsf{Mod}_A} f_*(f^* N \otimes_B M)$$

Always being a bit bad at algebra I did not notice the straightforward isomorphism above, and kept noticing the formal similarity between this identity and the adjunction between $f^*$ and $f_*$, but mysteriously the $\operatorname{Hom}$ has been replaced with $\otimes$. Indeed, this does not seem to follow from $f^*$-$f_*$ adjunction and $\otimes$-$\operatorname{Hom}$ adjunction relations in any straightforward way.

Assume for a moment that there is a functor $f^! : \mathsf{Mod}_A \to \mathsf{Mod}_B$ which is right-adjoint to $f_*$, that is to say, $\operatorname{Hom}_A(f_* Y, X) \cong f_* \operatorname{Hom}_B(Y, f^! X)$
for any $A$-module $X$ and $B$-module $Y$. The following sequence of utterly symbolic calculation ensues in an unhinged attempt to prove the aforementioned identity:

$$\begin{aligned}\operatorname{Hom}_A(f_*(f^* N \otimes_B M), P) &\cong f_* \operatorname{Hom}_B(f^* N \otimes_B M, f^! P) \\ &\cong f_* \operatorname{Hom}_B(f^* N, \operatorname{Hom}_B(M, f^! P)) \\ &\cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(N, f_* \operatorname{Hom}_B(M, f^! P)) \\ &\cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(N, \operatorname{Hom}_A(f_* M, P)) \\ &\cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(N \otimes_A f_* M, P)\end{aligned}$$

Since this holds for every $A$-module $P$, we would have proved $f_*(f^* N \otimes_B M) \cong N \otimes_A f_* M$. Except there is no such functor $f^!$, and in fact such a right-adjoint $f^! : \mathsf{Sh}(\operatorname{Spec} A) \to \mathsf{Sh}(\operatorname{Spec} B)$ to $f_*$ does not even exist at the level of sheaves, much less quasicoherent sheaves (Edit: This is not correct, the identity above tells essentially that $f^!(-) = \operatorname{Hom}_A(B, -)$ is the right-adjoint. See Roland's comments below). But once we pass to the derived category of complexes of sheaves, $f^! : D(\operatorname{Spec} A) \to D(\operatorname{Spec} B)$ exists as a right-adjoint to the derived pushforward $Rf_*$, see eg [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A9D). So it seems we can do the above computation by passing to the derived category, in which case we obtain an analogous derived version of the relation, $\mathscr{F} \otimes^{L}_Y Rf_* \mathscr{G} \cong Rf_* (Lf^* \mathscr{F} \otimes_X^{L} \mathscr{G})$ for any morphism $f : X \to Y$ between quasi-separated quasi-compact schemes, and $\mathscr{F}$, $\mathscr{G}$ being sheaves of $\mathscr{O}_Y$, $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules respectively.

In our particular case, it seems we can simply take the homology at the $0$-th grade (or the $0$-th derived functors) to obtain the isomorphism at the level of modules even though the calculation was happening in the derived category of sheaves or whatever. My question is, does this madness actually work? And is there an example of a more useful scenario where these kind of abstract arguments lets one avoid elementwise manipulation to prove certain identities? It seems the point of six functors formalism is that since everything is axiomatized, one doesn't need to think much to write these identities down. How wrong am I? This might be an extremely dumb question, I have close to no experience with these things. Apologies in advance.

Comment: But there is a right adjoint to the restriction of scalar functor : $f^!P=\operatorname{Hom}_A(B,P)$.

Comment: However, I am not convinced that everything is purely formal. Every "natural isomorphism" written using the six functor may induce equivalent isomorphisms by taking adjoint. But at least, one of them as to be established. In your example, the equality $f_*\operatorname{Hom}_B(M,f^!P)=\operatorname{Hom}_A(f_*M,P)$ is equivalent to the projection formula.

Comment: @Roland Oh of course, that formula literally is the restatement that your $f^!$ is the right-adjoint to $f_*$. This is confusing to me because from my experience with the category of sheaves over locally compact Hausdorff spaces, $f^!$ does not always exist. I guess this is an extremely special setup. Oh well, that makes the point of the question completely moot!

Comment: Some final curiosities now that the question has been established to be contentless: (1) If we did want to make it purely formal, could we argue $f_*$ is co-continuous and use the adjoint functor theorem? Then we have this mystery $f^!$ which we can do the above computation with (2) In general, when does $f^!$ exists for category of $O_X$-modules over schemes? I didn't expect it to be so simple for affine schemes (again, this just proves my incompetence)

Comment: What you called adjunction is not categorically speaking an adjunction : A categorical adjunction would be $Hom_A(f_*Y,X)=Hom_B(Y,f^!X)$ as sets (not as $A$-module). $Hom_A(f_*Y,X)=f_*Hom_B(Y,f^!X)$ is a commutation of the functors $f_*,f^!$ with the *inner hom*. My point is this commutation is by (categorical) adjunction the same as the projection formula. If you want to prove that $f_*$ has an adjoint by some categorical property (co-continuous...), you won't have the version with the inner hom, and you won't be able to derive the projection formula.

Comment: @Roland Huh, fair point. But even if I use the set-theoretic aka categorical adjunction formula, my calculation above holds: remove $f_*$ in front of the the internal Hom's whenever you see them and replace them by set-Homs, and the isomorphisms are isomorphisms of sets. Then you end up with a natural Set-isomorphism $Hom_A(f_*(f^* N \otimes_B M), P) \cong Hom_A(N \otimes_A f_* M, P)$. By Yoneda, that seems to give an isomorphism of $A$-modules $f_*(f^* N \otimes_B M) \cong N \otimes_A f_* M$, no? Or am I wrong again?

Comment: That's cheating. You think you can remove $f_*$ because it is a forgetful functor and does nothing specific. If it were sheaves, you couldn't remove it. In fact, in the expression $\operatorname{Hom}_A(N,\underline{Hom}_A(f_*M,P))$ the $\underline{Hom}_A$ needs to be a $A$-module, not just a set and it is important to give a specific module structure. The fact the module structure is the same as $f_*\underline{Hom}_B(M,f^!P)$ one is equivalent to projection formula.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks, that clarifies everything.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that projections formulas abound. There are more or less easy to prove, but it is a kind of relation using different functors (in this case $\otimes, f_*, f^*$). There may be formal relationships between a functor and its adjoint, but a relation between $f_ *$ and $\otimes$ can't be granted purely formally even with the additional assumption that they both have right adjoint. If they do have adjoints, the relation may be translated to another one using them but there still need a relation to be proved.